# Angularjs embedded data should show a link

Tags: angularjs

I have data coming form the server that contains href links. when I embed it in the template it shows the code and not the link. like html is not interpreted. Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/Al1_andre/pen/KMpqaQ).

The JS :

```
$scope.link = "<a href=''></a>";
```

and the template

```
<p>{{link}}</p>
```

How can this code shows a paragraph with a link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ng-bind and $sce. $sce will tell your app that the HTML is trusted. That being said, if you don't trust the HTML you are getting, you should be careful doing this (ie. if this is from users that you can't necessarily trust.) You may also want to look at sanitizing this.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="SOAngular" ng-controller="mainController">
  This should be a link and not pure text.
  <p ng-bind-html="link"></p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('mainController', function($scope,$sce) {
  $scope.link = $sce.trustAsHtml("<a href=''>test</a>");
});
```

I've forked your example with a solution here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxvOEX

References

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

```
<p ng-bind-html="link"></p>
```

Please refer [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) too, because you need to escaping your context with

```
$scope.link = $sce.trustAsHtml("<a href=''></a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you a scope variable with html in it !

```
$scope.link = "<h1>Big Nice Link here</h1>";
```

You should be able to output it as so

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="someHTML"></div>
```

..in your case it should be like this

[...]

```
<div class="item item-text-wrap" ng-bind-html-unsafe="link"></div>
```

[...]

also try this way too:

[...]

```
<div class="item item-text-wrap" ng-bind-html="link"></div>
```

[...]